# Stitching functions together using the ReaderT and StateT Monads

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers, state-monad

I am beginning with Haskell and I need help stitching functions together using the `ReaderT` and `StateT` Monads.

Ideally, if that is at all possible, all functions would have the same signature (which I understand those Monads should help with) and would be able to read the environment and alter the state.

The piece of code below is supposed to simply open a Socket in `openClientSocket` using an initial environment `initialNetwork`, inject the `socket` and `address` in the chain, then call the "next" function `func` which is passed as a parameter (function `sendMsg` in this case).

However I am facing multiple issues:

- a) how should I make the call to the passed `func` in `openClientConnection` ?
- b) the `HNT` Monad is composed (?) with other Monads. How do I read and manipulate the inner Monads ?

Could someone then please help me fix this code and if possible, derive/explain the "ideal" pattern to achieve the goal described in the subject.

Many Thanks

b.

```
import Control.Monad.Reader
import Control.Monad.State

import Network.Socket
import Network.Multicast

_MULTICAST_IP_ADDR_ :: HostName
_MULTICAST_IP_ADDR_ = "224.0.0.99"

_MULTICAST_PORT_ :: PortNumber
_MULTICAST_PORT_ = 9999

data NetworkEnv = NetworkEnv {
    getMulticastIP :: HostName,
    getMulticastPort :: PortNumber
} deriving (Show)
type NetworkEnvT = ReaderT NetworkEnv

data ClientSocket = ClientSocket { 
    getClientSocket :: Socket, 
    getAddress:: SockAddr 
} deriving (Show)
type ClientSocketT = StateT ClientSocket

type HNT m = ClientSocketT (NetworkEnvT m)

initialNetwork :: NetworkEnv
initialNetwork = NetworkEnv { getMulticastIP = _MULTICAST_IP_ADDR_, getMulticastPort = _MULTICAST_PORT_ } 


openClientConnection :: HNT m a -> m a 
openClientConnection func = do
    env <- ask
    (sock, addr) <- liftIO $ multicastSender (getMulticastIP env) (getMulticastPort env)
    put $ ClientSocket sock addr
    func   -- <== How do I call func (sendMsg) here ??


sendMsg :: String -> HNT IO ()
sendMsg msg = do
    NetworkEnv ip port <- ask
    ClientSocket sock addr <- get
    _ <- liftIO $ sendTo sock msg addr
    liftIO $ print "done"

doRun = runReaderT ( openClientConnection . (sendMsg "Hello") ) initialNetwork
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed the solution below; I am sure it can be improved and Error handling is not fully in place but it does obey the contract.

From all my readings, what really, really, helped me is [this paper](https://web.archive.org/web/20140821053740/https://www.grabmueller.de/martin/www/pub/Transformers.en.html) from Martin Grabmüller and realizing that the program runs **inside** a Monad: it is not a parameter to a function call (too many years of OO programming and injection calls)

```
import Control.Monad.Reader
import Control.Monad.State
import Control.Monad.Writer
import Control.Monad.Error

import Network.Socket
import Network.Multicast
 
_MULTICAST_IP_ADDR_ :: HostName
_MULTICAST_IP_ADDR_ = "224.0.0.99"

_MULTICAST_PORT_ :: PortNumber
_MULTICAST_PORT_ = 9999
 
data NetworkEnv = NetworkEnv {
    getMulticastIP :: HostName,
    getMulticastPort :: PortNumber
} deriving (Show)


data ClientSocket = ClientSocket { 
    getClientSocket :: Socket, 
    getAddress:: SockAddr 
} deriving (Show)


type HNError = String
type LogMessages = [String]

type HNT a = ReaderT NetworkEnv (ErrorT HNError (WriterT LogMessages (StateT ClientSocket IO))) a

runHNT :: ClientSocket -> NetworkEnv -> HNT a -> IO( (Either HNError a, LogMessages), ClientSocket) 
runHNT st env app = runStateT (runWriterT ( runErrorT (runReaderT app env) )) st

initialNetwork :: NetworkEnv
initialNetwork = NetworkEnv { getMulticastIP = _MULTICAST_IP_ADDR_, getMulticastPort = _MULTICAST_PORT_ }

initialState :: ClientSocket
initialState = ClientSocket undefined undefined

openClientConnection :: HNT ()
openClientConnection = do
    env <- ask
    (sock, addr) <- liftIO $ multicastSender (getMulticastIP env) (getMulticastPort env)
    put $ ClientSocket sock addr


sendMsg :: String -> HNT ()
sendMsg msg = do
    ClientSocket sock addr <- get
    _ <- liftIO $ sendTo sock msg addr
    tell ["Sent " ++ msg ++ " to socket" ]

myApp :: HNT ()
myApp = do
    env <- ask
    liftIO $ print (show env)


doRun :: IO ((Either HNError (), LogMessages), ClientSocket)
doRun = runHNT initialState initialNetwork ( openClientConnection >> sendMsg "Hello" >> myApp )
```

Comment: When you have a `Reader`, a `Writer`, and a `State` monad, you can use a `RWS` monad instead (except you sandwiched your `Error` monad smack in the middle...).  However, since the whole lot is riding on the `IO` monad, you might be better off using the error handling and state management facilities of the `IO` monad on its own.  You can always drop into a pure monad for the non-`IO` stuff.

Comment: @pat Thanks. The RWS Monad greatly improves the readability of the type HNT and runHNT

Comment: Oh, also, you shouldn't use `[String]` as your writer `Monoid`, since each append will have to traverse the entire list each time.  You're better off using `Data.DList` which has constant time append.  Also, if you want to ignore a result from a monad in a `do` block, just don't bind it (as opposed to binding it to `_`).